Using AlexaCRM/dynamics-webapi-toolkit I need to add a filter for a "modifiedon" datetime
As the title says, I am using the AlexaCRM/dynamics-webapi-toolkit package in a php project.
I have some code where I retrieve multiple records (That part works). However, I need to add a sort of filter where I only get the ones that has "modifiedon" for the last X days. Here is current working code
$pagingInfo = new \AlexaCRM\Xrm\Query\PagingInfo();
$pagingInfo->Count = 10;

$client = ClientFactory::createOnlineClient(
    'https://some-microsoft-crm.com',
    'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

$query = new QueryByAttribute('contact');
$query->ColumnSet = new \AlexaCRM\Xrm\ColumnSet(columnSet(true));
$query->PageInfo = $pagingInfo;

$result = $client->RetrieveMultiple($query);

The format for "modifiedon" is "2024-07-22T10:57:01Z". (This works if I put in the exact date for $query->AddAttributeValue("modifiedon", $twoDaysAgoDateTimeFormat);
I have tried adding a parameter as some other forum suggested, but it failed every time I did the request on this line:
$query->AddAttributeValue("modifiedon", 'ge ' . $twoDaysAgoDateTimeFormat);
or
$query->AddAttributeValue("modifiedon ge", $twoDaysAgoDateTimeFormat);
Any suggestions would be helpful.

First, the QueryByAttribute only supports operator " eq ". You can refer to source code line 400.
You should use FetchExpression instead.
Below code retrieves contacts that modified in the last 3 days:
$fetchXML = <<<FETCHXML
<fetch mapping="logical"> 
    <entity name="contact">
        <all-attributes />
        <filter>
            <condition attribute="modifiedon" operator="last-x-days" value="3" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
FETCHXML;

$fetchExpression = new FetchExpression($fetchXML);
$collection = $client->RetrieveMultiple($fetchExpression);

Here is the official tutorial.
BTW, FetchXml can also be generated with Advanced find(step1-3) and FetchXML Builder.

As you suggested, this is what I ended up doing. Works well enough. Although, I didnt know about the "all-attributes" tag, so will be trying out that. The links you posted are useful to know about. Thanks for your help :)

"all-attributes" tag is to retrieve all the attributes(same as SELECT * FROM contact in SQL); it is better to only select the necessary attributes for better performance.
